# View Git Repository on Heroku

Tags: git, heroku

I was wondering if it's possible or anyone has found a way to view their git repository graphically on a Heroku server? Like would it be possible to set up something such as gitalist on Heroku and then view the commits from the git you have set up for that app on Heroku.

Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heroku only runs Rack applications, so you'd need a Rack-based Git browser if you want to run it on Heroku itself.

But you could just mirror the repository on another server that has gitweb (or similar) installed, and you could even set up a cron job to clone between the servers.

What's your use case for this? It's hard to think of a situation in which this would be useful.

Comment: Well I had wanted to be able to login to the website and see what commits were being made to the same website - basically was looking for a system that would keep everything in one location.

Comment: Just clone the Git repository and look at it!